# Нейронная сеть перестает обучаться при достаточно высоком значении ошибки. (python, keras)

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Нейронная сеть перестает обучаться при достаточно высоком значении ошибки. Я полагаю, что проблема может быть в том, что на вход сети я подаю мало отличающиеся от друга друга значения. Например, 0.99962956, 0.99553886, 0.99457286, 0.99671779 и т.д. Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, правильна ли моя догадка и что можно сделать в такой ситуации.

Comment: Ну можете попробовать применить к данным MinMaxScaler из Sklearn перед обучением, но не факт, что дело в этом. Без конкретных данных и кода конфигурации нейронной сети можно только гадать, что у вас там происходит.

Comment: CrazyElf Спасибо, MinMaxScaler помог.